# Is the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-(\ln{k})^2}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Is the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-(\ln{k})^2}$$ convergent or
>   divergent?

I rewrite $e^{-(\ln{k})^2}$ as $k^{-\ln{k}}$. I know that $\sum_{k\geq1} 1/k^2$ is convergent. By the limit comparison test I get

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{k^{\ln{k}}}\cdot\frac{k^2}{1}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{k^2}{k^{\ln{k}}},$$

Clearly, for large $k$, $\ln{k}>2$ so the limit tends to zero. Thus, if $1/k^2$ is convergent, it follows that $e^{-(\ln{k})^2}$ is convergent.

**Is this ok?**

Comment: Yes, it's okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it right. You could do the algebra a little bit more directly by using $\ln(k)^2 \geq 2 \ln(k)$ for $k$ large enough (specifically $k \geq e^2$), which gives $e^{-\ln(k)^2} \leq e^{-2\ln(k)}=k^{-2}$ for such $k$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's ok, note that

$$e^{-(\ln{k})^2}=\frac{1}{k^{\ln{k}}}\leq\frac{1}{k^{2}} \quad k>e^2$$